# Is there a way to parameterize dplyr calls

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to parameterize dplyr calls
For e.g. if we had a dataframe as follows

```
    one two three
   1   1   2     5
   2   2   3     1
   3   3   2     2
   4   4   1     4
   5   2   3     6
   6   4   4     8
   7   5   5     7
```

Then I find I can parameterize the select calls, by finding out which column number the column name is. For e.g

I can have

```
 a <- df %>% select(2,3)
```

which selects column 2 & 3

But I find I cannot do the same for group_by

I am not able to do

```
b <- df %>% group_by(3) %>% summarize(x= sum(2))
```

I am forced to do

```
b <- df %>% group_by(three) %>% summarize(x= sum(two))
```

Can you please let me know how this can be done so that I can use a parameterized function which internally invokes dplyr calls based
on passed arguments

Comment: `group_by(names(df)[3])`?

Comment: you can hack your way around it but it's not natively supported, see: https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/1462

Comment: @Jaap I think you mean `group_by_(names(df)[3])` (using the standard evaluation version)

Comment: @MrFlick yes :-)

Comment: That does not work. I have tried group_by(df,names(df)[3]). It then creates one group with the colname "three"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @mtoto pointed out, [dplyr will not use column indexes](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/1462) because Hadley doesn't think it's a good idea. You could write your own helper function

```
group_by_index <- function(data, idx) {
    group_by_(data, names(data)[idx])
}
```

Then you can run

```
df %>% group_by_index(3) %>% summarize(x= sum(2))
```

Comment: That works. I did not initially notice the group_by_. Actually it can be very useful when I have to do similar operations on 'n' columns. Otherwise I have to code n different functions